# Python, Angle between 2 points

Tags: python

My vehicle is driving along it’s locale Y-axis. When it encounters a hill the front lifts up and creates an angle with the rear.  How can I ask python to return the angle for the vehicle to rotate on its X-axis ?

I found this but it doesn't work :

mathutils.geometry.box_fit_2d(points)
Returns an angle that best fits the points to an axis aligned rectangle
Parameters
points (list) – list of 2d points.
Returns
angle
Return type
float

[image]

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Answer (score 1):

to get the angle of the line you can pretty easily do it with a simple math

```
y1=kx1+l
y2=kx2+l
y1=kx1+y2-kx2
k=(y1-y2)/(x1-x2)
```

and this k is your tangent. so you just use numpy arctan

```
import numpy as np
angle=np.arctan((y1-y2)/(x1-x2))[0]
```

Comment: Must have done something wrong :-(
Blender sais ERROR : invalid Python expression
Var_1 = Z location empty front
Var_2 = Z location empty Rear 
expression : np.arctan((var_1-var_2)/6)

Comment: i'm not sure about this specific problem. but from your picture it looks like its just a 2D so it would be odd to have a Z value. for me it looks like variable that you have as Z is actually Y and variable Y is actually X. im just guessing. have nothing to say as the formula is correct. looks like its application specific error and i have no knowledge in that field. try posting the question with blender tag. good luck

Comment: I posted this in the wrong Community. I went to Blender with my question. Sorry guys, my mistake :-(

Comment: @Karel_VT could you link to your new Question here?

Comment: Ya sure : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193102/how-to-ask-blender-to-return-an-angle-of-a-tangent-in-a-driver/193103?noredirect=1#comment323598_193103